# Multiple instances of browser opening up when running test through webdriver manager

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdrivermanager-java

I am new to Selenium, so basically whenever I ran my test, it would open up the URL which I have mentioned in my test. In my same Test I have also mentioned to fill the username and Password.

But somehow once the browser gets launched and redirect to the URL, it opens up another instance of blank browser failing my script that element not found.

Please help me here.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public class TruefillTest extends BaseClass  {


  public Truefill truefill()
  {
    WebDriver driver=InitializeDriver();
      return new Truefill(driver);
  }


@Test
    public void userLoginIntoTheSystem()
    {
        truefill().dashBoard().Url();
        truefill().dashBoard().EnterUsername("bjdgfe@swcwr.com");
        truefill().dashBoard().EnterPassword("Test1234");
    }
///////////////////////////////////////////////

public class Truefill  {
   private WebDriver driver;

    public Truefill(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver=driver;
    }

  
    public DashBoardPage dashBoard()
    {
        return new DashBoardPage(driver);
    }


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public class DashBoardPage  {
    
        private final WebDriver driver;
        By Username= By.xpath("//input[@name='name']");
        By Password= By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'exampleInputPassword1')]");
    
    
        public DashBoardPage(WebDriver driver) {
            this.driver=driver;
        }
        public void Url()
        {
            driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/");
        }
        public void EnterUsername(String username)
        {
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.findElement(Username).sendKeys(username);
    
    
    
        }
        public void EnterPassword(String password)
        {
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.findElement(Password).sendKeys(password);
        }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public class BaseClass {
    WebDriver driver;

public WebDriver InitializeDriver()
{

    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
     driver = new ChromeDriver();
    return driver;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each call to the `truefill()` method initializes a new instance of WebDriver. Since your test is calling it multiple times, it will start a new browser instance on each line. Instead, store the `DashboardPage` in a local variable:

```
@Test
public void userLoginIntoTheSystem() {
    DashBoardPage dashBoardPage = truefill().dashBoard();
    dashBoardPage.Url();
    dashBoardPage.EnterUsername("bjdgfe@swcwr.com");
    dashBoardPage.EnterPassword("Test1234");
}
```

You might also want to use a setup method to initialize the `Truefill` instance, rather than creating it on demand:

```
private Truefill truefill;

@BeforeEach
public void  initializeTruefill() {
    WebDriver driver = InitializeDriver();
    truefill = new Truefill(driver);
}


@Test
public void userLoginIntoTheSystem() {
    DashBoardPage dashBoardPage = truefill.dashBoard();
    dashBoardPage.Url();
    dashBoardPage.EnterUsername("bjdgfe@swcwr.com");
    dashBoardPage.EnterPassword("Test1234");
}
```

This assumes JUnit 5. If you're using JUnit 4, the annotation is `@Before` instead of `@BeforeEach`.